# Storing data from MySql in PHP (Back to basics)

Tags: php, mysql

here is the log for the result of my sql SELECT using PHP:

```
224=[Array containing 1 elements]
iProduct=[604]
```

where 224 is the line number. and iProduct is the Column Heading

How do I do I make a variable that just contains the value of the return (not an array or anything) (i.e. $var = 604 in this instance)?

Having issues with the basics here lol

Comment: Maybe you could post some code? We dont know which mysql-Extension your are using. (PDO or mysqli or mysql)

Comment: maybe array_pop?? or current($array);

Comment: Please put the relevant PHP code and MySQL query in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL, you shouldn't need to sort in your script. Instead, sorting should be done using the database; as it will sort faster than PHP would be able to do. Example:

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC FROM myTable WHERE colA = 'foo' ORDER BY colB DESC
```